# Sorting an array objects by property having null value

Tags: javascript

I need some help in sorting an array of objects.

The object has property `value` it can have either `100 or 0 or null.`

I want to sort this array in descending order but null should always come in the end.

**Example 1**

Input

```
array = [{key: a, value: 100},{key: a, value: null},{key: a, value: 0}]
```

Expected output

```
array = [{key: a, value: 100},{key: a, value: 0},{key: a, value: null}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
  var valA = a.value == null ? Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER : a.value;
  var valB = b.value == null ? Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER : b.value;
  return valA - valB;
})
```

Comment: @simbada try it in your browser console - output is `9007199254740991` on my browser's console

Answer (score 0):

You could check the value and use a very large value as sort value.

```js
var array = [{key: 'a', value: 100},{key: 'a', value: null},{key: 'a', value: 0}];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.value === null ? Infinity : b.value) - (a.value === null ? Infinity : a.value);
});

console.log(array);
```